# Dataset of adulteration incidents

Tags: data-request, medical, food

I'm looking for a dataset of [adulteration incidents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adulterant#Incidents_of_adulteration) containing as many following fields as possible:

- name of the adulterant(s) (an adulterant is a substance found within other substances such as food, beverages, fuels, although not allowed for legal or other reasons)
- name of the substance that should have been present instead
- date of the incident
- location (e.g. country): if the good has been exported, if possible both source and destination locations.
- amount of affected products (e.g. 1.5 ton of milk powder)
- number of casualties

Even if the database has one or two of those fields I'm still interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Here is a [Food Fraud Database](http://www.foodfraud.org/). I haven't used it, but for some
  reason it was in my bookmarks.

> The first publication of the database in 2012 includes more than 1300 entries based on more than 650 articles. This includes information on more than 350 different food ingredients. Each record in the database is a publicly reported unique combination of food ingredient, adulterant, and where available an analytical detection method published in one literature reference.

- Here is a [Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_food_contamination_incidents) with a few dozens of incidents.
- Here is [a paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/enhanced/doi/10.1111/j.1750-3841.2012.02657.x/) (*Development and Application of a Database of Food Ingredient Fraud and Economically Motivated Adulteration from 1980 to 2010*). They said that they would created a Database. Maybe you could contact with them or read the paper and find any citation.

Comment: Thanks, great paper: the DB they refer to is http://www.foodfraud.org. The only issue is that I don't see any good way to export it without scraping :/